# Как добавить стиль для каждого элемента ListView?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, style

Вот такой стиль я хочу добавить для кждого item моего ListView. Как это можно сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="20dip" />
            <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="#127BCD" />
            <solid android:color="#21F3F0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="20dip" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#127BCD" />
            <solid android:color="#21F3F0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="20dip" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#127BCD" />
            <solid android:color="#21F3F0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас должна быть разметка для items. В ней допустим родительский элемент - Linearlayout. Просто пропишите для него свойство background и присвойте ему в значение имя файла стиля

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)